# C++ dynamic properties

Tags: c++

I don't know if dynamic properties is really the right term, but I want to be able to define properties at run-time via some container. The usage I'd be looking for would be something like the following:

```
Properties p;

p.Add<int>("age", 10);

int age = p.Get<int>("age");
```

I can't seem to work this out because the container of each setting would need to be in a templated class but I don't want classes for each primitive type like int, float, etc. Is my usage above possible in C++?

Comment: C++11 auto might work

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention this wouldn't be in C++11 and non boost if possible. I swear I did this once before but can't seem to find any code.

Answer (score 3):

I remember now. The trick was to use a base class that isn't templated and then make a child class that is templated and use the base class in the container to store it and templated functions to handle it.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Prop
{
public:
    virtual ~Prop()
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Property : public Prop
{
private:
    T data;
public:
    virtual ~Property()
    {
    }

    Property(T d)
    {
        data = d;
    }

    T GetValue()
    {
        return data;
    }
};

class Properties
{
private:
    map<string, Prop*> props;
public:
    ~Properties()
    {
        map<string, Prop*>::iterator iter;

        for(iter = props.begin(); iter != props.end(); ++iter)
            delete (*iter).second;

        props.clear();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Add(string name, T data)
    {
        props[name] = new Property<T>(data);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T Get(string name)
    {
        Property<T>* p = (Property<T>*)props[name];

        return p->GetValue();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Properties p;

    p.Add<int>("age", 10);

    int age = p.Get<int>("age");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think either `boost::any` or `boost::variant` in combination with `std::map` will do what you want.

Comment: Any options without boost and have a roll your own? Just for fun :)

Comment: @user441521 sure.  Take a look at `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.  Write basically the same interface in `my_name_space::any` or `my_name_space::variant`.  Get it wrong, swear in frustration, and just use `boost`.

Comment: I'm looking at boosts any/variant and it just seems bloated. I swear I've done something like this before without it (with much less code), but I can't find any code.